# WP8 App crashes while trying to create instance of Writablebitmap in c# -Insufficient memory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, image-conversion

I would like to do a Image conversion in image to byte array and byte to image in windows phone app.
now,i tried to covert image to byte conversion,for that

first i create an instance of writablebitmap class with argument as uielement 
(i.e)

```
WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(Imagecontrol,null);
```

in this line app getting crashes because of

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

how can i solve this issue in wp8 ?

Comment: How large is the imagecontrol you're adding?

Comment: image file size - 3.52 kb,image control height=100 width =100

Comment: That's nothing that should cause an issue... I have used WriteableBitmap with well over 100kB allocated to it. Are you performing this on multiple images?

Comment: yes,while changing images in multiple times

Comment: Any suggestions for resolving insufficient memory in wp 8 apps

Comment: I would follow Olivier's solution and be wary of how many images you're working on at once.

Comment: Is there possible to reduce the size of image? because size of images from cameracaptureTask  is above 1.25 MB in windows phone 8 .

Comment: When I go into my camera and go to settings, I have something like 8 different sizes I can choose from.

Comment: what is the reason to get insufficient memory issue,i tried a different code to solve this,but not working. because of image size is it coming?

Comment: On the phone you are severely limited in the amount of memory you can be using at any given time. When you try to use more than you are allowed (150-300MB depending on the phone), you'll get the error you've posted. If you are really working on hundreds of images, you should probably work on 10-20 at a time to keep your memory usage within what's available.

Comment: OK,is there possible to keep paging in longlistselector in windows phone 8 to avoid this issue

Comment: i'm loading images in list 10 to 20 only but again memory issue coming

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `WriteableBitmap` constructor that takes an `UIElement` parameter, because you already have the `WriteableBitmap` within the `Image` control.

Just cast the `Source` property of the Image control as WriteableBitmap:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = Imagecontrol.Source as WriteableBitmap;
```

Maybe that will avoid the Out of memory Exception.

Comment: yes,i tried like this , WriteableBitmap btmMap = Img as WriteableBitmap; while getting byte values Img.SaveJpeg() code, object reference set to an instance of an object exception coming, how can i solve this?